# How to update the elements of array in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, url

I want to replace the Item of an array to the newly created item here is the function

```
 $scope.getPageDetails = function () {
        $http.get('/api/privilege/getpagedetails/')
            .success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.Pages = data;
                angular.forEach($scope.Pages, function (value, key) {
                    var url = "//" + (value.pageUrl);

                    console.log(url);
                    $scope.Pages.pageUrl = url;
                });
                $scope.$applyAsync();

            }).error(function () {
            });
    }
```

I got the value of **pageUrl** from array  **$scope.Pages[]**  which is **recoveryguidance.com**
then I added **//** on the pageUrl `var url = "//" + (value.pageUrl);`
then it becomes **//recoveryguidance.com** then how can I push the updated value on array $scope.pages[] in the place of pageUrl.
In short I want to update value from recoveryguidance.com to //recoveryguidance.com of pageUrl column in $scope.pages array.

I am attaching the data also I want to update pageUrl recoveryguidance.com to //recoveryguidance.com.

[image]ageUrl

Please guide me I will be very thankful to you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.Pages, function (value, key) {
    value.pageUrl = "//" + (value.pageUrl);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitishkumarsingh13/Lvc0u55v/13069/)